# what will come "should" or "shall"?

Tags: should

**What should i do?**
 or
**What shall i do?**

Which is correct.
Note: Im poor in English. So araised this question. I didnt get any proper answer for this question.. 
Give me proper answer with reason.

Comment: To put it more simply: both are grammatically correct. Without knowing more detail of what you want to say, it is impossible to tell you which is the right choice.

Comment: Please explain the sentences which i mentioned. how to use them

Answer (score 0):

What should I do ? and what shall I do ? are two different sentences.
Should indicates the imperative that you ought to do something.
Whereas shall seeks guidance on a choice which is not quite so desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Should implies a moral imperative but is not necessarily what you will do. Shall is what you will do.

when you say "i shall eat", there can be no doubt that you will eat. wether you should or not might be a very different story.

Answer (score -3):

both sentences are correct. it is just depends upon in which tense u want to use for. now the thing is if u want to speak in past you need to use should and if you want to tell or speak about future you can use shall.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not correct. If you want to frame the sentence in the past tense, you would write "What should I have done?"

Comment: Please do not misspell "u"  on ELU.